# Debug/Release variable not propagating to library Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run my app in debug / release mode. But there is a problem that the debug mode in app is not propagating to library. This is known issue in Android Studio and gradle. while finding solution to it, came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312743/workaround-to-link-a-shared-library-in-debug-mode-with-android-studio-v2-0-beta/35338493#35338493) in SO. While implementing it, After the step 1, I am getting the below error.

```
/home/geetha/geethaNew/App/stethocloud/build/intermediates/bundles/release/res/layout/fragment_stetho_connect.xml
Error:(72, 20) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored').
Error:(62, 20) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar').
```

The corresponding layout element is

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/connectProgressBar"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Can someone point out whats going on here and how to resolve this issue? This is a show stopper as of now to me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your "styles.xml" file?  Also can you post the "build.gradle" file?

Comment: Thanks @AndroidGuy.  I fixed this issue. The reason being the recommended solution needs to be implemented in all the dependent libraries and it should be done step by step clean/rebuild process.