# How can I debug C++ source code of a native library using Android Studio 2.3?

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk

I have made a clean install of Android Studio with SDK (android-studio-bundle-162.3764568-windows.exe) to a Windows 10 box, added SDK's from 5.0 and up, NDK plus other parts required to run C++ code under Java, plus added all updates available.

I've then created a new project with C++ support, `min SDK=5.0`, and Empty Activity template.

Run / Debug `app` works fine on my Android 6.0 device, and I can see that the C++ code returns a string which is displayed on the screen.

Breakpoints set in the Java code works fine, but breakpoints set in the C++ code doesn't cause the app to stop when run.

This seems to me to be a plain vanilla example that should work 'out-of-the-box' as according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html), but obviously something is missing.

---

Now I know what the problem was. The default administrator user in a Swedish Windows installation is called 'Administratör'.

When I installed AS 2.3 as 'Administratör' I put the project files and SDK under 'C:\Data\Android' which worked fine according to the installer. But breakpoints for C++ code didn't work.

So I tested to uninstall SA and log in as 'Administrator', which is the default Windows Domain administrator name, and installed AS 2.3 exactly as done while logged on as 'Administratör' (Project and SDK still under 'C:\Data\Android'). Now C++ breakpoints worked fine.

So what's the difference? Well, SA 2.3 puts some catalogs under 'C:\Users\username' such as '.AndroidStudio2.3', '.lldb' . 
I suspect that the 'ö' in the username is causing some problem when SA tries to reference these catalogs, but this isn't the installer aware of. 
Otherwise would it have been a piece of cake to check the username for "illegal" ASCII characters.

Comment: Has anyone ever managed to debug C++ code using AS 2.3 ín some configuration?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674434/debugging-native-libraries-for-android-os/47132384