# How to use and debug native shared libraries with Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm having a hard time finding an up-to-date answer to this question. Many existing answers refer to older versions of AS, and are now obsolete.

I want to use a precompiled debug build of a C++ shared library. I also want to be able to step through calls to this library.

I have successfully created a basic app with NDK support and some JNI code. I can step through the JNI code in the debugger.

Two questions:

1. How do I add the shared library and its headers to the app?
2. How can I reference the source code of the precompiled library so that it can be accessed in the debugger?

I am not a C++ expert, so please explain in noob terms. Thanks.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674434/debugging-native-libraries-for-android-os